# Tirar carateres em variavel

Tags: javascript, string

Tenho uma variavel com o seguinte conteudo 00:00:01. Quero tirar o dois pontos para ter como resultado final 000001. Utilizo o split mas o resultado que tenho é 00,00,01.

```
var res = min_time.split(':');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilize a função [replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp), que faz a substituição de *string*. O primeiro parâmetro é a *string* que deve ser substituída e o segundo parâmetro é o que vai substituir o primeiro. O primeiro parâmetro aceita tanto uma [expressão regular](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp) como uma *string*. Exemplo:

```js
var teste = "00:00:01";
var teste2 = teste.replace(/:/g, "");
alert(teste2);
```

Lembrando que ao utilizar *string* ele vai substituir apenas a primeira ocorrência. Exemplo:

```js
var teste = "00:00:01";
var teste2 = teste.replace(":", "");
alert(teste2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Então, quando voce utiliza o comando `split`, ele quebra a "palavra" e o transforma em um array, cada trecho que ele encontra separado pelo delimitador `:` ele armazenara em um espaço do array, se quiser continuar utilizando-o dessa maneira, basta voce fazer o seguinte:

```
hora = res[2]+''+res[1]+''+res[0];
```

Detalhe importante: O JavaScript é bem chato quanto a tipagem de objetos, se voce simplesmente fizer algo do tipo:

```
res[2]+res[1]+res[0];
```

Em vez de considerar como uma `string` e concatenar pra ter o resultado esperado, ele irá somar as partes, porque ao 'ler' um número, ele irá interpretar como um objeto do tipo `number`, por isso há a necessidade das aspas simples...

Obs: Eu recomendo utilizar o comando `replace`, de acordo como o @Earendul passou ;]

Answer (score 2):

Por padrão, o .toString () de uma matriz vai usar a vírgula como delimitador,você também pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
var res = min_time.split(':').join('');
```

da uma olhada nesse link. [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)